# Remote Access Problems with DRAC 5 on Dell PowerEdge 1950

Tags: local-area-network, dell-poweredge, drac

Today I received my first Dell PowerEdge 1950 server with a DRAC 5 card.  On my local network I have static configurations on my Linux systems using this for instance:

iface eth0 inet static

- address 192.168.1.210
- netmask 255.255.255.0
- network 192.168.1.0
- broadcast 192.168.1.255
- gateway 192.168.1.1
- dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

For the DRAC card, I configured the LAN like this:

- address 192.168.1.215
- netmask 255.255.255.0
- gateway 192.168.1.1

For the advanced LAN settings I used

- dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

I've tried many different IP addresses, but cannot communicate with the card.  Is there anyone who might know if I have configuration issues, or maybe if the card might be bad?

Comment: Is the DRAC NIC selection configured as Dedicated or Shared? If Dedicated, do you have a network cable plugged into it and to your switch?

Comment: The DRAC NIC selection is Dedicated.  I have a network cable plugged into NIC 1, and one plugged into the DRAC card.

Comment: Problem resolved, because your reply helped. The cable I connected to the DRAC was on an incoming line directly to the Internet instead of through the router.  Thank you Joe!

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: @Darin: When you get a chance, post that information as an answer and flag it as accepted. (you're allowed to do that after some time passes) It helps to cut down on the number of "unanswered questions" that accumulate over time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cable I connected to the DRAC was on an incoming line directly from the Internet instead of through my router.  Connecting the cable through the router solved the problem.